# Combine aerial imagery pictures to create a layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, imagery, aerial-photography, education, software-recommendations

We are looking for software or a web service that we can put in pictures we took using our weather balloon to create a single image, that we can use as a layer for our GIS project. Preferably free, or free for education.

EDIT: We use a ESRI system

Comment: How many images are you working with?

Comment: A few hundred, our camera is setup to take a picture every few seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Towson University geospatial research & education lab has done something similar. They used Microsoft Image Composite Editor to mosaic pictures captured from a balloon and Microsoft Photosynth for capturing and viewing in 3D.

http://pages.towson.edu/morgan/bap/BAP_Poster.pdf

See the contact info on the PDF for more information/questions.

Comment: Thanks! just tried the software referenced in the document, and it works great. And it is a very similar project.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear its similar enough to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if software is quite good enough yet to do this automatically, though I know Microsoft Research was doing some cool stuff along these lines a few years ago.
Ah, here we are, [PhotoSynth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosynth)

An alternate option is manually georeferencing with something like [QGIS](http://qgis.org/) or [GvSIG](http://www.gvsig.org/web/) or any one of a number of free Open Source GIS. Then Mosaic them together using [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) or its ilk.

You can possibly outsource the work, but as you likely have students around its probably a better idea (cheaper and educative) to get them to do it.

Answer (score 0):

We have not ever tried it, but could be interesting: http://mapknitter.org/

I guess it needed an internet connection with a important speed!

Good job!